# If the input size of a recursive function decreases by 2 is it a factorial time algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, factorial

I have a recursive definition as follows:

> f(input_array) = {f(input_array - i)  for i in input_array, if len(input_array) > 1; 0, else}

I know that this is a factorial solution, because the size of the input decreases by 1 at every iteration.

The size of the input looks as follows:

`n
n-1
n-2 
n-3
...
n-(n-1)`

This is clearly a factorial time solution. I'm wondering what happens the input size decreased by size 2. Would that also be factorial?

Answer (score 3):

The time complexity is n⋅(n-2)⋅(n-4)⋅...⋅2.

When *n* is even, it can be rewritten as follows:

[2⋅(n / 2)] ⋅ [2⋅(n / 2 - 1)] ⋅ [2⋅(n / 2 - 2)] ⋅ ... ⋅ (2⋅1) = 2<sup>n/2</sup> ⋅ (n / 2)!

---

Interestingly, there is a term that denotes the initial product of factors that differ by 2, *double factorial*, and it uses the *n!!* notation (thanks to Ari Hietanen for indicating it in the comments) -- see these links on [wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html) or [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial) for additional properties of this expression.

Comment: Thanks, but how in the world to you get `2* (n/2)` ?

Comment: @echo 2 * (n / 2) is a useful way of writing _n_. It is useful, because after factoring out a "2" from each number we get consecutive values, whose product can be conveniently written as a factorial.

Comment: Or rather, what's the logic that you had for doing that?

Comment: Thanks, that makes a bit more sense. Why can it be conveniently written as a factorial?

Comment: @echo because factorials are products of consecutive numbers (there is no notation for products of numbers which differ by 2). Maybe an example is useful. If n = 10 (the above works only for even n), then the product is 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 * 10 = (2*1) * (2*2) * (2*3) * (2*4) *  (2*5) = 2^5 * 5!

Comment: @echo also, it's useful to try to write it using factorials and other standard operations, instead of letting it in the original longer 2 * 4 * ... * n form, because it sometimes provides additional insights in the order of magnitude of the respective expression. For example 2^(n/2) * (n/2)! is neither 2^n (it is larger than this), nor n! (it is smaller than it).

Comment: Thanks - that makes more sense. I'm confused on how you get 2^n/2 though. Shouldn't it be 2^n?

Comment: @echo the 2^(n/2) comes from grouping together the factors with value "2" from each of the (n/2) parentheses. See the example with n=10 above (there are 5 parentheses, each one starting with a "2" factor).

Comment: This kind of product is called double factorial and denoted by n!!. More info in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_factorial

Answer (score 0):

Compute the same. `n`, `n-2`, `n-4`, ..., `2` or `1`. Hence, time complexity would be `O((ceil(n/2))!)`. For `n` even, we have:

```
n/2 * (n-2)/2 * ... * 1= n/2 * (n/2 -1) * ... * 1 = (n/2)!
```

In the other words, you should count down the steps. the number of steps from `n` to `1` with length 2, can be `n/2` steps. About the `ceil` I should say it is about odd numbers. For example for `n = 5` we have 3 steps to `1` so it would be `ceil(5/2)`.

Comment: Where does the ceil come from? How are you converting n-2 to n/2?

Comment: The input size decreases by n-2 not by n/2. So I'm confused where you're getting n/2 from

Comment: @echo OK. You should count down the steps. the number of steps from `n` to `1` with length 2, can be `n/2` steps. About the `ceil` I should say it is about odd numbers. For example for `n = 5` we have 3 steps to `1` so it would be `ceil(5/2)`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the response. However, this still doesn't make any sense to me. With length 2, it should still be n-2 not n/2. n/2 is if we're dividing the input by two and running the recursive function on each piece -- like in merge sort.

Comment: Any other insights??